# Remove OTA installed iOS 8 and reinstall on itunes

Tags: software-update, ios, iphone

hey guys i have the iOS 8.1 update on my iPhone 5s. I have downloaded iOS 8 over-the-air and it takes up too much storage space. So I was wondering if it is possible to delete that update to go back to iOS 7 and re-download iOS 8 on itunes so it can take up less space.....

Comment: Not clear about what you mean by `... iOS 8 over-the-air ... takes up too much storage space`. Where do you see this space taken up? If you are having problems with your iPhone, your best bet is to back it up to your Windows or Mac with iTunes.app, then restore iOS8, then restore your settings.

Comment: ios 8 over the air means downloading by wifi...... and i see that takes up too much space. I have heard that if you download ios 8 though itunes then that will be less space taken up rather than wasting 1 GB though the wifi method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in space required *after the upgrade* whether you upgrade iOS over the air or via iTunes. The only known problem is that you need more free space *on your iOS device* before/during the upgrade if you do it over the air. But as you already seem to have downloaded the upgrade to your phone this doesn't seem to be an issue for you, so just apply the upgrade on the phone and you are done.